# Get value that is outside scope of filter

Tags: tableau-api

I'm working on a tableau project with long format table data displaying start months, end months, and monthly costs. I'm trying to display a visual of a (dynamic) range of dates' monthly costs, and then overlay a reference line of the multi-month row's total cost. I suspect the answer lies in using a level of detail (LOD) expression but can't seem to figure this out.

example csv:

```
start,end,month length,x,a,b,c,d,total
1/1/2019,1/1/2019,1,1.2,0.08,0.01,0.1,0.299,0.489
2/1/2019,2/1/2019,1,1.1,0.08,0.01,0.1,0.295,0.485
3/1/2019,3/1/2019,1,0.9,0.08,0.01,0.12,0.285,0.495
1/1/2019,2/1/2019,2,2.3,0.08,0.01,0.1,0.297086956521739,0.487086956521739
2/1/2019,3/1/2019,2,2,0.08,0.01,0.109,0.2905,0.4895
1/1/2019,3/1/2019,3,3.2,0.08,0.01,0.105625,0.2936875,0.4893125
```

*ignore x,a,b,c,d - they are to show that the chart has multiple measures equaling the monthly totals.*

For identical start and end months, we have a `month length: 1`. The values associated with these rows are the monthly values. For graphing a dynamic range of months, I can graph these monthly values by filtering the `month length: 1` and adding a calculated field filter for setting the start date to end date range `[Start Date] >= [Selected Start Date] AND [Start Date] <= [Selected End Date]`

[image: Example Pic]

Given this table, how might I show a reference line for the `total` value that exists for the start to end range selected (`start date: 1/1/2019`, `end date: 3/1/2019`, `month length: 3`), even though there is a filter of `month length: 1`? The end result here would be a line of `0.4893125`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, you need to use LoD.

If you need to bypass the filter then use LoD `Fixed`, below code snippet will give you the data for `month = 3` though the filter is `month=1`. Change the code as per your requirements:

```
{ FIXED : Max(IF [Month Length] = 3 THEN [A] END)}
```

Edit----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
{ FIXED : 
Max(
IF ([Start Date] >= [Selected Start Date] AND 
[Start Date] <= [Selected End Date]) AND
[Month Length] = 3 THEN [A] END)}
```

Comment: Hi Siva thanks for your response - and what if I want the value from row 4? Seems like a multi criteria problem

Comment: @EvanFriedland replace 3 with 4, if its dynamic create a parameter and use that instead which will change dynamically

Comment: I meant row 4, not term length 4 - that i understand. You will notice rows 4 and 5 both have the same term length of 2, starting and ending on different dates.

Comment: @EvanFriedland check my edit, in that case take month length and mix with start and end date.